# Fake Call, Iphone

Tags: iphone, call

Anyone know how to code and have a fake call pop up in an Application, so I can use my own audio? I know several apps have done this, just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a UIView that look likes the interface when someone is calling you.
2. Prepare an audio file playback using AVAudioPlayer
3. When the apps runs, show that interface, and playback the audio file.

You can include stuff like timer settings and notification so that it will fires off 5 minutes later or something.